# Does a file system snapshot include deleted files?

Tags: backup, snapshot

Let's say I create backups by file system snapshot once per day at midnight. Of course, after the snapshot is created, it will be archived to a separate drive.

If you create a lot of temporary files and delete them afterwards do these files increase the size of the daily snapshot?

Or is the snapshot only the delta between yesterday 00:00 and today 00:00?

Comment: What software are you using; are you using any specific options with that software? Please add to the question, its hard/impossible to answer your question if we don't know what you're using to take snapshots of your filesystem.

Comment: It would be an LVM snapshot. Maybe I should ask the backup colleagues.